# Convert nullable numeric into string

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I want to convert a nullable numeric into a string **maintaining** the null value. This is what I'm doing:

```
int? i = null;
string s = i == null ? null : i.ToString();
```

Is there something shorter?

Comment: Don't think there is anything shorter actually

Comment: Other than an extension method, don't see this getting any shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an extension method for that:

```
public static string ToStringOrNull<T>(this Nullable<T> nullable) 
where T : struct {
  return nullable.HasValue ? nullable.ToString() : null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var s = i.ToStringOrNull();
```

**UPDATE**

Since C# 6, you can use the much more convenient [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
var s = i?.ToString();
```

Comment: Oops.. This time I'm sorry - just wanted to create more generic version of my answer :) I didn't copy yours!

Comment: I need formatProvider parameter for decimal type so removed generic version to specialize to decimal extension as my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47835010/1830909, Unfortunately can't write method in comment and must be written as new answer, do you have any better idea?

Answer (score 8):

You can write some extension method:

```
public static string ToNullString(this int? i)
{
   return i.HasValue ? i.ToString() : null;
}
```

Usage will be more simple:

```
string s = i.ToNullString();
```

Or generic version:

```
public static string ToNullString<T>(this Nullable<T> value)
    where T : struct
{
    if (value == null)
        return null;

    return value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry about adding a similar answer, it's just that I thought of a more generic version than yours....

Comment: No sense keeping my answer as yours is effectively the same in a much cleaner extension method +1.

Comment: @Clodoaldo actually he is not :)

Comment: OK, I'll +1 you so that I don't feel so bad for being selected... Even if I get unselected that's fine...

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
string s = i?.ToString();
```

is shorter.

Comment: Yes! +1. But you have to appreciate that this question was asked and answered before that operator was available in the language. Nevertheless, I've updated my answer with that as well.

Comment: Yeah, was aware that the question predates the availability of the operator. Just thought I'd throw it out there in case it's helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use System.Convert i.e.

```
int? i = null;
string s = Convert.ToString(i); // it gives null if i is null.
```

And as already mentioned we can also use null conditional operator

```
string s = i?.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

I need formatProvider parameter for decimal type so removed generic version to specialize to decimal extension as below:

```
public static string ToStringOrNull(this Nullable<decimal> nullable, string format = null)        
{
    string resTmp = "";
    if (nullable.HasValue)
    {
        if (format != null)
        {
            resTmp = nullable.Value.ToString(format);
        }
        else
        {
            resTmp = nullable.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        resTmp = "";
    }
    return resTmp;
}
```

Comment: @Jordão Yeah, I have some nullable decimal field in my db tables therefor in entity framework model defined as nullable decimal. For using them in web app view, must be convert to string and as nullable type I can't using the standard ToString() method.